# Change Gimp units from relative to absolute

Tags: gimp, guides, units

Is there a way to change the guide units from relative to absolute when moving them on GIMP?

Also is there a way to add a guide on the edge of the image? I can add a guide on 0,0 but not on (max,max)

Regards

[image]

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, although you can add a new guide by using *Image > Guides > New guide*, and input the value in pixels directly. There's also a *New guide by percent* in the same location. And yes, by using these functions, guides can be set to the edge of the image, at 0px or 100%.  Is this useful to you?

Comment: Yes... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the guide units from relative to absolute when moving them on GIMP?

No need to, you already have the information:

[image]

And yes, even if you click slightly outside the guide, the values are corrected so that:

```
initial guide position + the offset (the values you circled) = actual guide position
```

> Also is there a way to add a guide on the edge of the image? I can add a guide on 0,0 but not on (max,max)

No problem for me... But keep in mind that the outer guide for a 200px image is at 200, not 201, because the leftmost pixel is between coordinate 0 and 1, so the rightmost pixel is between `width-1` and `width`.

Besides zooming, three easy ways to add guides on the edges:

#### Measure tool:

- *View>Snap to canvas edges*
- Start measure tool
- Click near a corner (tool will snap on corner)
- Alt-Ctrl-click again to create vertical and horizontal guides that cross at that point

#### Script

[`ofn-guide-from-layers`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) will create the guides that delimit a layer, if the layer is as big as the canvas (background layer, for instance) this will also be guides that delimit the canvas.

#### Do nothing

As hinted in the solution with the Measure tool, you can do *View>Snap to canvas edges* so that canvas edges behave like guides in 99% of the uses of guides.